# join across databases with nhibernate

Tags: database, nhibernate, orm, join

I am trying to join two tables that reside in two different databases. Every time, I try to join I get the following error:

```
An association from the table xxx refers to an unmapped class.
```

If the tables are in the same database, then everything works fine.

Comment: please provide the exact query you are attempting

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this error. But I have also faced problems in joining tables from different databases in a procedure. I created temp table in one of the databases and then inserted data from the other table and did join using temp table with table in the same database.